# Trying to Scrape Manta but getting nothing

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I know this is a header issue because if I take the header out of my code then the html spits out that I am a bot but I can't figure out how to get around this issue even when I add headers. What advice can you give?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


#Get the different pages to begin scraping data from
url = "http://www.manta.com/mb_41_ALL_19/louisiana"
headers = {    'Origin':'http://www.manta.com',
        'Referer':'http://www.manta.com/mb_41_ALL_19/louisiana',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36'
        , 'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.8'
        ,'Content-Type':'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'Host':None,}
newurl = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(newurl.text, "html.parser")
print(soup)
```

Comment: Their CDN is using browser fingerprinting to block bots. It can be done with requests but it means reverse-engineering some javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad news, look at what you've got at the `body`:

```
<div id="distil_ident_block"></div>
```

The `distil` is a sign of the "Distil Networks" anti-web-scraping service. And they have their reasons. Quote from the ["Terms of Service"](http://www.manta.com/resources/page_terms_conditions/):

> We give you a limited right to access and use Manta. *You are not
>   authorized to access Manta or its computers, servers and databases to
>   scrape or “data mine” our data.*

Technically, you can challenge Distil, but legally you should not.

Comment: Yikes that sucks! Oh well on to the next project :) Thanks

Comment: @Kamikaze_goldfish they have a way of detecting selenium as well (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver) - it can be apparently workarounded, but they'll have more challenges for you. In any case, in this case web-scraping would be illegal. I'd say your best bet would be to be explicit - contact the manta.com owners/maintainers and ask for a better way to get the data, stay on the legal side of things.